# Permissions help on LAMP setup

Tags: php, linux, permissions, lamp

I have a slight problem with a CMS set up on a LAMP setup. The CMS has a file manager which was working fine, with ownership of folders and files in the the file manager set up as miller.psacln, with file permissions in this folder set to 777. This is on a private server, so although i realise permissions should not ideally be set to 777, i thought it would be ok in this instance.

Anyway, there have been some changes to configuration on the web server, and new files are now being uploaded with ownership as apache.apache, file permissions set to 755. I realise this is the correct setup, but I have a problem in that this conflicts with the ownership and permissions of the rest of the files and directories which the file manager has access to. Should I now change all affected directories to 755 apache.apache, given that the apache user is now running as apache.apache?

This is probably basic stuff, just hoping to clarify this before I do anything drastic!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, change the file permissions to the user running the web server. (apache:apache).

This way (if the CMS file manager is driven by apache as well) you will be able to access both old files and create new ones.

Your minimum requirements should be 0700 both for files and directories, everything owned by the apache user. The group won't matter, but if you make it group writable, you could put `miller` in the apache group.